# iOS custom framework, libraries, and bundles

Tags: ios, frameworks, bundle

I have a general question regarding bundles, libraries and custom frameworks on the iOS. I've seen many topics about this on SO and searched far and wide on the net, but I still can't come to an answer without finding another site or post contradicting or confusing me some more. If someone could give me a solid answer to the below questions regarding what is allowed on the iOS or what would get rejected I would be really grateful.

- I've seen posts and sites say that you cannot create bundles on the iOS. Does this also apply to bundles with only images in them?
- Is it possible to create a library with .xib files in them? If not then how would one go about including one if custom frameworks are not allowed?
- Does using a xCode dynamic library put my application for grounds of rejection (ex. libxml2.dylib)?

Apologies if this is too general or mentioned multiple times, but this whole library and what is allowed and what isn't allowed just doesn't seem to be very clear for me. What I am trying to do is to create some apps and perhaps include some controls that I frequently use in some sort of library or bundle, but I would like to know my limitations before moving further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.: No, you cannot create any framework even if it contains images only, as you can't write to the root partition of the iOS filesystem (the part where /System/Library/Frameworks resides).
Of course, if jailbreaking is an option, then all this stuff becomes invalid. You do what you want with a jailbroken phone, so you can create frameworks, add libraries to the filesystem etc.

2.: Yes, it is possible to create a library with XIB/NIB files with it, but then you'll need to share both the source or a static library built from the sources AND the XIB files and guide the other developers to do so in order iOS to correctly handle your library and be able to build the UI from the InterfaceBuilder files.

3.: No, because those libraries are already on the iPhone, you don't have to hack it to get them on the filesystem. libxml2, libsqlite3, etc. are allowed and can be used in any AppStore app.

Comment: Sorry about this, but can you clarify how or if something like this can work? It's things like this that confuse me. http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/#framework_ios

Comment: he's not buulding a shared library but emulates a framework by usig a 'static library'. It means that he almost does the same thing that he would if he simply compiled all sources together.

Comment: So what he is doing is allowed on the iOS?

Comment: of course, it's not different from directly linking the source of a library to his/one's project. You should really look up how compilers work and what the difference between a static and dynamic library is.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. the only part that really had me confused was the bundle/framework information. Even in my question I asked if bundles were allowed and I saw posts stating that they aren't because, as you mentioned, they need root partition write access. Thank you for clarifying everything for me in the end though. Greatly appreciated.